# How to get the special string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the special string in javascript.

Example:

JAMES SEVERA - 1679581110 - Physician/Psychiatry - 100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503

Here are Doctor's name, position, and address.

I just need the address only. (100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503)

I am going to use this address for the Google map.

Comment: Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You're expected to try to solve the problem first. If you get stuck somewhere then it's a good idea to ask a specific question here based on your own solution attempt; providing a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean). Refer to [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is always formatted like

NAME - ID - POSITION - ADDRESS

then you can split by the separator and just take the last element of the array:

```
const str = "JAMES SEVERA - 1679581110 - Physician/Psychiatry - 100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503";

const strArray = str.split(" - ");

const address = strArray[strArray.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split() function for this.
Like this:

```
var str = "JAMES SEVERA - 1679581110 - Physician/Psychiatry - 100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503";
var address = str.split(" - ")[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string will always be consistent in this format, with address as last and the fields separated by an hyphen then this  should do it

```
const { length, [length - 1]: address } = "JAMES SEVERA - 1679581110 - Physician/Psychiatry - 100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503".split('-');

console.log(address); // prints '100 EAST BROADWAY, COUNCIL BLUFFS, IA 51503'
```